# Removing a redundant parent class in LESS?

Tags: css, less

I have this LESS:

```
.border-dashed {
    border-style: dashed;

    &-1 {
        border-width: 1px;
    }

    &-2 {
        border-width: 2px;
    }
}
```

Which generates the following CSS:

```
.border-dashed {
    border-style: dashed;
}

.border-dashed-1 {
    border-width: 2px;
}

.border-dashed-2 {
    border-width: 2px;
}
```

However note that there is now the `.border-dashed` class which will only set the border style, I don't want people to use just this class. Is there a way I can not generate this class, in order to enforce the usage of either `.border-dashed-1` or `.border-dashed-2`?

I could use the following but then properties are duplicated.

```
.border-dashed {  
    &-1 {
        border-style: dashed;
        border-width: 2px;
    }

    &-2 {
        border-style: dashed;
        border-width: 2px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put your `&*` selectors in a list like so:

```
.border-dashed {  
    &-1, &-2{
      border-style: dashed;
    }
    &-1 {

        border-width: 2px;
    }

    &-2 {
        border-width: 2px;
    }
}
```

Which gives the result:

```
.border-dashed-1,
.border-dashed-2 {
  border-style: dashed;
}
.border-dashed-1 {
  border-width: 2px;
}
.border-dashed-2 {
  border-width: 2px;
}
```

Which should have the result you are looking for.

This isn't 100% ideal because you do have to include all of the variations in that list for the common properties, rather than it be automatic based on the hierarchy. If that becomes cumbersome then there is an option to use a mixin. Although you are back to having to repeat it in all of the sub-blocks you still have the benefit of a single point of update, and can be especially useful if you have many common properties.

```
.border-dashed {
    .common(){
       border-style: dashed; 
       border-color:red;
       //whatever
    }
    &-1 {
        .common;
        border-width: 2px;
    }

    &-2 {
        .common;
        border-width: 2px;
    }
}
```